# forEach usage with bootstrap grid system

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, foreach

I'm working on a blog site (in node.js), created a blog Schema, a forEach loop iterates over every blog and adds image, title,body to it :

[image: like this :]

Code :

```
   <% blog.forEach(function(blog) { %>

      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">

                <a href="/blog/<%= blog._id %>"><img src="<%= blog.image %>"></a>
            <div class="caption">
                <a href="/blog/<%= blog._id %>"><h2><%= blog.title %></h2></a>
            </div>

            <span><%= blog.created.toDateString(); %></span>

            <div class="relative">
            <p><%- blog.body.substring(0,250); %></p>
            <div class="absolute"></div>
            </div>

       </div>

    <% }) %>
```

Because I've applied forEach, all blog posts have the same appearance.

Is there any chance that the 4th and 5th blog posts appear in different ways(col-md-6, i.e they both occupy half the space of the row)?

Comment: Have you tried using :nth-of-type? http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter of the `forEach` callback is for `index`:

```
<% blog.forEach(function(blog, idx) { %>
<% if (idx > 3) %>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
<% else %>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
```

Comment: After your suggestion, the 4th and 5th items look like : [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUu7p.jpg
I added thumbnail class (bootstrap class) to images, now it's a bit better :https://i.stack.imgur.com/iueyR.png

Comment: But what I wanted to do was something like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9x03.png
They have the first 3 blog items similar to my way, but their 4th and 5th posts are different. Putting them together can be done, but how did they use the image as background and the title in it(just for 4th and 5th items)?  Are they doing it manually (without a loop)?

Comment: It looks like the ones in the Polygon pic are called out as 'features'. I don't know the details on the page. Perhaps they have one loop for regular blogs and another for featured blogs.

Comment: Do you think that they have different mongoose schemas for regular and featured blogs?